# What is the proper way to Dispose of my ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, .net-3.5, datacontext

I am not quite sure of what the proper way to `Dispose` my `ObjectContext` is. Here is how I am setup:

```
public abstract class DataManagerBase<T> where T:ObjectContext
{
    protected T _context = null;

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public DataManagerBase(T context)
    {
       _context = context;
    }
}
```

To use this in other classes, I am doing something like:

```
public class Test : DataManagerBase<DataEntities>
{
     public Test(DataEntities context) 
        : base(context){}

     public void InsertRecord(Person p)
     {
         if(_context != null)
         {
             try
             {
                 //Do insert logic
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {

             }
         }
    }

}
```

I have other methods that use the same `_context`, so I am not using a `using` statement, so should I check if the `_context` is not null if an exception is thrown and then dispose it?  Basically I want to ensure that the _context is disposed when I am done with it, whether there is an exception or not.  Would adding a `finally` to every `try/catch` be incorrect?

Would adding this method to my DataManagerBase class and then calling it in other classes do the trick:

```
 public void DisposeContext()
 {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
 }
```

Comment: You're calling base on something that doesn't inherit from anything?

Comment: As a quick and dirty solution, yes, adding a null check and `dispose()` method to your finally statement works just fine. The more optimal solution is to encapsulate all calls inside a `using` block for your context.

Comment: @MystereMan - Sorry fixed. Forgot to add it.

Comment: @BradM -  I hear you about the using statements, unfortunately it wasn't done that way, so now I have to ensure it is closed, so I guess if it isn't over kill, I could just had a finally to everything?

Comment: @BradM - calling dispose at the end of each method in a `finally` will mean you won't be able to call other methods on the same instance of that object.

Comment: @Xaisoft where does the context come from?  Is it shared (ie per web request)?  If so, it should probably be the responsibility of the provider to dispose of it.

Comment: @drch - Per web request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule of the thumb is: do not Dispose of objects which you did not create. So you should not dispose your context in any of the classes you provided to begin with.

You should however call `context.Dispose()` in class, where you actually create this particular instance. And when you do - there should be no other object using it. What you are trying to do is to avoid design issue you have instead of fixing it. Thats wrong, imho. And that will bite you back at some point, when you'll forget to put yet another null check somewhere.

Using the code you provided the example might look like:

```
void SomeMethodInOuterScope()
{
    var context = new DataEntities();

    var test = new Test(context);

    try
    {
        test.InsertRecord(new Person());
        ...............
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ....
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is another example (when context is not local)

```
class SomeClassInOuterScope : IDisposable
{
    private DataEntities _context;

    public SomeClassInOuterScope()
    {
        _context = new DataEntities();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var test = new Test(_context);
        test.InsertRecord(new Person());
        ...............
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}

void SomeMethodInOuterOuterScope()
{
    var someclass = new SomeClassInOuterScope();

    try
    {
        someclass.Test();
        ...............
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ....
    }
    finally
    {
        someclass.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would use `using` in my `DataManagerBase` class?. I also added a method to my post for the `DataManagerBase`, but not sure if this would be correct?

Comment: @Xaisoft again, you should dispose of your context in the smae class where you create this instance. You did not create context in DataManagerBase (you simply pass existing instance to constructor) so you shuld not dispose it there. call `Dispose()` in the same class where you call `new DataEntities()`

Comment: Ok, so correct me if I am wrong, in one of my controllers, I am doing `DataEntities _context = new DataEntities()` in the constructor, but what you are saying is instead of this, I should put it in a `using` statement everywhere I use it, for example in a InsertRecords method.

Comment: Afaik, creating context is pretty cheap. But it keeps cached entities you worked with. Unless you need them for some subsequent operations better to kill contexts fast.

Comment: @Nik - Thanks, this is what I had in mind, so pretty much just `disposing` it in a `finally` should be good enough.  Is there a reason why you did not `dispose` of it in the `catch`?

Comment: @Xaisoft, yes. If you call `Dispose()` in `catch` block, you will only call it when there is an exception. Which is wrong. You should call `Dispose()` when you no longer need this instance of context (e.g. when you _either_ have an exception, _or_ you are done using it)

Comment: @Nik, one last question, in order to do this, I have to declare the context inside the method that is using it. I can't declare a global context variable because then closing it would make it unavailable to other methods, correct?

Comment: @Xaisoft, yes, correct. You should get the idea by now, but i've added another quick example just in case

Answer (score 3):

The best is to create and delete it in one place. Like

```
using(var context = factory.CreateContext())
{
    // use your context
}
```

Comment: If this is the correct/best way, is it worth it to update it in every place?

Comment: Yes, for consistency at least. You will need to create an implementation of your abstract class somehow. If the abstraction is mandatory creating some kind of factory could be a solution.

Comment: I have that, for example I have some manager classes that implement the DataManager class.

Comment: Then you have one problem less :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add a `Dispose` method on your abstract class. Maybe implement IDisposable.

Let the provider of the calling code use a `using` block.

So on the abstract class:

```
 public void Dispose()
 {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
 }
```

Calling code:

```
using(var db = new Test())
{
... 
}
```

The downside of this is you're relying on the calling code to manage the disposable of your context.

Comment: I understand the Dispose method part, but if I am in my Test Class, why would I do using(var db = new Test()?

Comment: because the `using` statement on the Test class with directly call the `Dispose` method on your abstract class once it leaves the context of that `using` block

Answer (score 0):

It's not absolutely necessary to dispose of the context, although it is probably desired. The garbage collector will eventually dispose it, and entity framework uses ado.net connection pooling so it will not really be holding a connection.

It's not the utmost efficient to do this, but it won't cause any leaks, unless you have leaks in your class itself.  Whenever your Test class goes out of scope, then the context will eventually be disposed by the gc.

You would really only be concerned if you were creating a lot of these objects over and over again, which is probably not the case.

I'm not suggesting this is a good practice, but if this is a bug fix of some type, or a temporary thing.. it's probably not necessary.

Comment: Well I ran into a StackOverFlow exception yetersday and I suspect this may have something to do with it :)

Comment: @Xaisoft - No.  Stack Overflows occur when you recursively call something.  There's no way that not disposing of an object can do that.  You have to look at the call stack and see what methods are being called over and over.

Comment: Thanks, I found the cause of the StackOverFlow, I had a method calling itself, lol. Thanks.